# Reactjs - Passing functions to Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know you can pass functions from parent to child components, but can you somehow pass functions to a Link? Like (ignore the fact it's relative):

`<RelativeLink get_inputs={this.get_inputs} activeClassName="blue-active" to='start'>Start</RelativeLink>`

Comment: Isn't `RelativeLink` a React Component? Then you can pass it props, including functions.

Comment: `Link` from `react-router`? Then an onClick can be the effect. but use a span inside the same: `<Link ...><span onClick></span></Link>` if using span use `import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';` anyways, please provide more code to showcase.

Comment: @NagarajTantri well my Link activates a component, and was wondering if it was possible to pass the function to that router component. Though I worked out that I didn't need to do this function passing anyhow. I just left it up because it might be interesting.

Comment: @A.Lau for passing functions/methods to a component, via router, is usually done with actions and `connect` of redux. So you link cannot tell the handler. Instead your link can specific query params and in the component you choose which function to invoke